# How can I scale a subsection of a mesh created with the screw modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, screw-modifier

I've created a mesh that somewhat resembles a phone cord by following [this tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/05/09/rigging-a-spiral-phone-chord-in-blender/).  Now I want to modify a subsection of the structure.  Specifically, I would like to scale down the "diameter" of the structure somewhere in the middle.

Is there any way to do this besides creating separate meshes for each of the differently-sized subsections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are trying to adjust the Curve path in this case, you can follow this way:

- Tab into the Edit Mode, select one or more points on the curve;
- Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to loosen or narrow it as you want (or click **Scale Feather** button in the Toolshelf).

[image]